# AWS S3 File Upload, getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, amazon-s3

I am uploading file to S3 using ajax method. My file is successfully uploaded (got 204 code) but still (ajax is going in fail method instead of success) getting error,
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

my crossdomain policy is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*">
</allow-http-request-headers-from>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

my ajax method,

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(){
      console.log("success")
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log("error")
    }
  })
```

Comment: Are you able to see the image if you call image url directly in the browser?

Comment: No, but when i try to access on s3 browser and after copying link of particular image and pasting on browser able to see image.

Comment: Image permission are set correctly? copied url is working after you logged-out from aws console?

Comment: Yes, When I logged out from s3 then after pasting image url to browser able to see image

Comment: Have you created cloudfront url for access the images? Can you paste img url here.

Comment: Yes, I made that . it is like, https://my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/folder_name. sorry cannot share the url

Comment: please see the answer below and let me know if this worked.

Comment: I had used same configuration ,policy and same  ajax method for other uploads and they are working but I don't know why it is giving such error.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this document http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html

Below is the sample xml you can try. Change the `examplesite.com` to yours. Right click the bucket and go to "Permissions" tab and click "Edit CORS Configuration"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*.examplesite.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```